# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://SharePoint/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to upload file to sharepoint using webservice.
We have separate server for Sharepoint.
If I publish and debug in my workstation, I get System.IO.FileNotfoundException: The Web application http://Sharepoint could not be found, but if I open the webservice url on Sharepoint server, I am able to upload the file successfully.
I have full admin right on Sharepoint. 
I know this is permission issue but I don't know what kind of permission I would need in order to run this.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Can you ping Sharepoint from your dev box? If not, that's your first clue.

Comment: Error says it all. Are you sure you have correct web service URL? Can you show some code?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint OM (likle SPSite/SPWeb...) in your webservice.

Comment: "but if I open the webservice url on Sharepoint server, I am able to upload the file successfully." - Clarify what you mean here. Do you mean "when you run your code local to the server", or "when you open the URL in the browser on your dev machine"?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging will not work OOTB except locally on the server the code is being published to. You should be able to debug your code from the http://Sharepoint server.